# sperm reaction of virus infected

Tags: microbiology, immunology

we know when a human body cell infected by a virus , create interferon 1 to call other cells that surrounded it  , but red blood cells couldn't do this because they loose their nuclear and other organelles . I have a question about sperms , can sperms produce interferon 1 when they infected with viruses?

Comment: Could you please be a little more precise and specify the virus that you have in mind that infects sperm?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: well David I don't have any special virus just I ask this in general